# undefined control sequence }

Tags: horizontal-alignment

l can't figure out the error. The error is after `\end{minipage}`. Is it a problem of brackets?

```
\begin{figure}[!ht]

\hspace*{-2cm}

\centering

 { \fbox{

\begin{minipage}[t]{150mm}

\footnotesize

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2.5}

\resetline

\begin{tabbing}

{\bf Function} {\sf Consensus}($v_i$)\\~\\

\end{tabbing}

\normalsize

\end{minipage}

 } % **HERE IS THE ERROR**

 \caption{Protocole de consensus indulgent en absence de défaillances}
 }
 \end{figure}
```

Comment: How is `\resetline` defined? Does it come from a package?

Comment: Welcome, if this is based on a template, throw it away and read some introductory material. This code is bad and will lead to more (much more) confusion and disturbing behviour later on.

Comment: This code is a mess!

Comment: Instead of only posting code please explain what the code is supposed to do.  Then it is easier to help you! Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1):

The error is actually at another place. It reads:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...elinestretch }{2.5} \par \resetline 
                                                  \par \begin {tabbing} \par...
l.30  }
```

This tells us that `\resetline` is the undefined command (=control sequence).

I could not readily find a package where it is defined, so maybe it was once defined in the preamble your code seems to stem from.

Commenting the `\resetline` line to:

```
% \resetline
```

solves the problem.